# How to trigger SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener events when Activity opened rather than pull the trigger

Tags: android

In android, how do I trigger SwipeRefreshLayout OnRefreshListener events when Activity is opened rather than pull the trigger?

Comment: try using mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true); in on create.where mSwipeRefresh is your swipe refresh view.

Comment: I want to open the Activity has a drop-down animation effects, how to implement

Comment: show what have you tried so far.